# Dive into something

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Can you say intead of lose yourself in music  ***dive into*** music? In terms of "to be so interested in something that you do not notice what is happening around you"(macmillandictionary source)

Comment: ***Dive into:***
to start doing something in a very enthusiastic way - 
*Let’s dive into the improvements that you can make right away.* https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/dive-into

Answer (score 2):

The expression you are looking for is: ***[Immerse oneself in something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/immerse):***

> to become completely involved in something:
>
> - *She got some books out of the library and immersed herself in Jewish history and culture*

(Cambridge Dictionary )

> Immerse oneself in music!!!

Comment: What about "to dive into atmosphere of something"? Is it ok?

Comment: No. See the first comment above. You can't really dive into something you're merely a passive listener to, it just doesn't work.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. I can see that "soak up" is correct to use this way, but i don't get why is "incorrect immerse" and "plunge into" to use, can you please detailedly explain for me? Thank you!

Comment: It's the difference between passive & active. You can immerse yourself in a passive activity like listening to music, but you dive into an active one, like learning to play an instrument.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. Ok, thank you, I appreciate, but would it be correct to say "you dive into the atmosphere of learning to play instrument?"

Comment: Not really. 'atmosphere' is passive, 'learning' is active, so you're kind of mixing your metaphors a bit. Probably no-one would notice, but it doesn't really sit well.